# what does threading.Thread do?

Tags: python

I have this code here:

```
t = theading.Thread(target = arping)
t.start()
```

Can someone please explain to me what does threading.Thread do?
I know it may seem like a stupid question, but I don't understand this line.

Comment: What does reading the Python documentation say?

Answer (score 2):

That line creates an instance of the `threading.Thread` class. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The line `t = threading.Thread(target = arping)` creates a `threading.Thread` class with a call to `arping` by the class `run()` method.

Basically, that means that the script will run the `arping` function in a new and separate thread.

The second line `t.start()` actually starts the thread, which in turns calls the `run()` method which will run the `arping` callable object.

About the concept of *threads*, you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201852/what-is-a-thread-really).

As tbrisker said, you can have more info on the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects).