# What is a thread in a kotlin coroutine?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin

I have read many questions here and several books on kotlin coroutines, but none answers the question of what a thread is.
For example, I run an app on my huawei gr5, which has 4 cores. But people are talking about spawning 128 threads on the dispatcher.IO.
Is this `thread` the same as the logical thread when we say an Intel i5 cpu has 6 cores and 12 `threads` or is it just a concept, a `set of CPU instructions`?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a "thread" (really)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201852/what-is-a-thread-really)

Comment: I did read this, but was not sure if it is connected with kotlin coroutines in particular so I asked this question.